# What is this random arrow in the centre left of my Chrome screen?

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android

Arbitrarily an arrow appears on the center left of my mobile Chrome browser. I cannot even click this arrow. It doesn't really affect any underlying features of my web browsing, at least not on the obvious. It is just a bothering little arrow, which has no reason in being there.

My phone details are:

```
My phone is: Samsung Galaxy M31
Model: SM-M315F/DS
Application version: Chrome 92.0.4515.131
Operating system: Android 11; SM-M315F Build/RP1A.200720.012
```

Attaching screenshot of my Chrome browser where the arrow can be seen.[image: Screenshot with the arrow marked with question marks]

As far as I can recall, this arrow disappears without any apparent activity.
Had anyone seen this? Or can shed some light as to what this is? And if it can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Google forums-When I rotate the phone an obnoxious arrow overlays the middle of the screen?](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48825508/when-i-rotate-the-phone-an-obnoxious-arrow-overlays-the-middle-of-the-screen?hl=en), force stopping worked.
You may try restarting if issue is not resolved.